# Syntax Error: Missing Exponent in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been getting syntax error. Missing exponent everytime I run my Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function randomendtime(len) {
 var chars = ["10.202", "11.121", "12.101", "13.111", "14.121", "15.097", "18.142", "20.926"];
 return chars[ Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
}

var 2et = randomendtime(1);

document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/' + 2et + '"><\/script>');

</script>
```

Comment: why is your variable starting with 2...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your variable name `2et` is invalid; JavaScript variables names can contain numbers, but may not start with them.

The reason you are getting an error about exponents is because JavaScript number literals may be written in scientific notation (e.g. 2e3, or 2000). Whichever JavaScript engine was running this code parsed the variable name as a malformed number literal, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

change the variable name which you have given "2et" and give string  as a variable name it will work....

Comment: Perhaps you want to be a bit clearer than "give string" as to what will work.